# Query a column for row values in HDFS

Tags: python, hadoop

I have a tab delimited text file in hdfs that is output from some text analytics someone else built that looks like thus. The real file is 18k columns wide and when it is refreshed monthly the number of columns are not static, neither are the column names.

```
Product ID    [I love peanuts]    [Your mom is silly]   [Let's eat pizza]
P-ABCD               0                     0                     1
P-1234               1                     1                     0
```

I need to write a program that will search or query for "Let's eat pizza" and return P-ABCD.

I'm using Python at the moment, but I'm new to both python and map reduce, so I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to solve this one. The situation is weird enough I haven't found anything else with a solution.

I'm thinking if I could pivot the "table", so that it looked like this:

```
ProductID  Phrase 
P-ABCD     [Let's eat pizza]
```

That would be easier to work with, but I'm not sure which language or technology would be best. Any thoughts on how you'd solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file.txt

```
Product ID  I love peanuts  Your mom is silly   Let's eat pizza
P-ABCD  0   0   1
P-1234  1   1   0
```

code

```
import csv

def search(search_column, search_value):

    with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
        header = []
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
        for row in reader:
            if not row:
                continue
            if not header:
                header = row
                continue
            row = dict(zip(header, row))
            if row.get(search_column) == search_value:
                return row.get('Product ID')
        return None

print search('Let\'s eat pizza', '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def searchTable(look_for):

    import shlex
    import re

    l_rows = []

    with open("1_table_data") as f:

        for line in f:
            line = line.replace("Product ID", "Product_ID")
            line = shlex.split(re.sub('[\[\]]','\"', line))
            l_rows.append(line)


    index_of_look_for = l_rows[0].index(look_for)

    for i in range(1, len(l_rows)):
        if int(l_rows[i][index_of_look_for]) == 1:
            print(l_rows[i][0])
```

searchTable("Let's eat pizza")

P-ABCD

searchTable("I love peanuts")

P-1234

searchTable("Your mom is silly")

P-1234